# ExternalLoginInfo Email is always null in Microsoft and Facebook oauth2, MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm using the following code for `ExternalLoginCallback`
In `google` everything is OK. but in `Facebook` and `Microsoft` `loginInfo.Email` is always null.
What's wrong with the following code?

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    // loginInfo.Email is always null, so FindByEmailAsync throws an exception
    UserIdentityModel user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginInfo.Email); 

    if (user != null)
    {
        await SignInAsync(user, false);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
    return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel
    {
        UserName = loginInfo.DefaultUserName,
        Email = loginInfo.Email
    });
}
```

I'm using the following packages:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: Haven't yet used Microsoft oAuth, but with Facebook you need to specifically ask for email permissions in the configuration of your facebook app, otherwise you will not get the email address.

Comment: I've done it, and I checked email.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution, We have to use `Facebook` and `Microsoft` as the following in `Startup.Auth.cs` file:

```
// Facebook
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = "---",
    AppSecret = "---",
    Scope = { "email" }
});

// Microsoft
app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "---",
    ClientSecret = "---",
    Scope = { "wl.basic", "wl.emails" }
});
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem for Yahoo OAuth2 authentication. The email is null after successful authentication. Do you have solution for Yahoo authentication please?

Comment: I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29998559/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-email-at-externallogincallback

Comment: After doing this, still `info.Email` is null for me.

Comment: After doing this, still info.Email is null for me

Comment: info.Email is null still.

Comment: if email still null, please add 2 more properties like @Bimal Das update bellow. It work for me

Answer (score 8):

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AppId = "",
                AppSecret = "",
                BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
                UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,location",
                Scope = { "email" }
            });
```

Create a class :

```
 public class FacebookBackChannelHandler : HttpClientHandler
    {
        protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Replace the RequestUri so it's not malformed
            if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
            {
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("?access_token", "&access_token"));
            }

            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Microsoft accounts, but only those which were associated with personal accounts (i.e. hotmail) and not business/school accounts. After trying several of the answers above, I was still not receiving the email address despite the user giving permission to my app.

In the end, what solved this for me was updating the OWIN packages in my project to version 4.0. After that, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Mohammed's answer. No dice. 
I tried Bimal's answer. No dice.

Finally, I upgraded all my OWIN references using Nuget. Now it works.

If the other answers don't work, try upgrading all your Nuget packages w/ respect to all the OWIN items.